# ifdef syntax doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macros, conditional-compilation

I want dynamically define a constant based on the different device heights.
I tried to use this code but it doesn't work:

```
#define isPhone568 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)

#ifdef isPhone568
    #define kColumnHeightPortrait568 548
#else
    #define kColumnHeightPortrait568 (IS_IPAD ? 984 : 460)
#endif
```

Even if i'm using the 3.5" simulator, i get 548. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run code in macro definitions, it's a simple text substitution process that happens at compile-time. Hence you have no idea what the device characteristics are at that point, because you're not *on* the target device.

If you want to use something like `[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom`, you have to evaluate it at *run-time,* not in a compile-time macro, something like:

```
int kColumnHeightPortrait568 = 548;
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
   || ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height != 568))
{
    kColumnHeightPortrait568 = (IS_IPAD ? 984 : 460);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#ifdef` is used to check whether a macro is defined. As you define `isPhone568` in the first line, `#ifdef isPhone568` will be true.

If you want to test the value of an expression rather than the existance of a macro, you should use `#if` instead. But `#if` can test no more than the simple arithmetic expression, just as **paxdiablo** mentioned, "You can't run code in macro definitions".